# ML Engine Python Version Issue

Tags: python, virtualenv, google-cloud-ml

While going through a [flower classification tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/flowers-tutorial), I ran into a python issue. Trying to run the trainer preprocess script with the command

```
python trainer/preprocess.py \
    --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
    --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
    --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
    --cloud
```

I get the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 71, in <module>
    import apache_beam as beam
  File "/Users/some_guy/Documents/Programs/ML/cmle-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    'It is not supported on Python [%s].' % sys.version_info)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

This sounds like my (`virtualenv`?) path has the wrong python.

`python -V` returns

```
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Which may be wrong, because my `cmle-env` is activated (it prefixes my terminal prompt), so I thought the `cmle-env` would know the right python version to use so that I don't run into dependency issues. I followed the tutorial instructions verbatim, and had gotten a previous [census data tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/getting-started-training-prediction) to work just fine before (within the same `gcloud` project).

I am very new to `gcloud` and `virtualenv` so maybe I missed something (e.g. it is strange that `python -V` returns `anaconda 3.6`, which is on my host and I don't believe has anything to do with the activated `cmle-env`).

TLDR: How do I get my `cmle-env` to use the proper python version so that I can run the flower tutorial trainer? I really want to continue - these are fantastic other than python issues.

This is run on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to specify the python version you want when you create the virtualenv using the `--python` or `-p` option, as in:

```
$ virtualenv -p /path/to/python2.7 cmle-env
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Apache Beam and it was fixed a year ago: https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/30b5fe552cbf40a6914d327ac5455394ee615493

Comment: The condition hit is the problem, not the raised message. I updated Apache Beam and simply get the returned error message from the fix.